# SQL Select from 1 table rows with 2 specific column value that are not equal

Tags: sql, select, join, rows

I have a table

```
id  number    name    update_date
1   123       asd       08.05.18
2   412       ddd       08.05.18
3   123       dsa       14.05.18
4   125       dsa       05.05.18
```

Whole table consist from that rows like that. I need to select row 1 and 3 because I need different update_dates but same number. How to do that? I need to see the changes from specific Number between 2 update dates 08.05.18 and 14.05.18. I have more update dates in my table.

I tried:

```
SELECT *
FROM legal_entity_history a
JOIN legal_entity_history b ON a.BIN = b.BIN
WHERE ( a.update_date <> b.update_date AND
        a.update_date = "08.05.18" AND
        b.update_date = "14.05.18" )
```

Comment: You want to select all rows that have same number as row 1 and all have different dates?

Comment: Your expected result seem need only one filter in WHERE clause. What did you try so far?

Comment: SELECT * FROM legal_entity_history a JOIN legal_entity_history b ON a.BIN = b.BIN WHERE ( a.update_date <> b.update_date AND a.update_date = "08.05.18" AND b.update_date = "14.05.18" )

Comment: i need to display dates 08.05.18 that are not equal to 14.05.18

Comment: You use a column BIN to join, but according to the sample data there's no such column.

Comment: `a.update_date = "08.05.18"` is invalid (standard) SQL. Which DBMS product are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A relatively simple method is:

```
select leh.*
from legal_entity_history leh
where exists (select 1
              from legal_entity_history leh2
              where leh2.number = leh.number and leh2.update_date <> leh.update_date
             );
```

For performance, you want an index on `legal_entity_history(number, update_date)`.

Answer (score 0):

**TRY THIS:** Assuming that same number may not appear more than once under same `update_date`, so, you can achieve that using `GROUP BY` with `HAVING` as below

```
SELECT t.*
FROM test t
INNER JOIN (SELECT number 
            FROM test 
            GROUP BY number 
            HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT update_date) > 1) t1 ON t1.number = t.number
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
id  number  name    update_date
1   123     asd     08.05.18
3   123     dsa     14.05.18
```